# Solution to $y''-axy'-by=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is $v$,
$$v(x)=\int_0^1e^{\frac{ax^2}{2}t}t^{\frac{b}{2a}-1}(1-t)^{-\frac{b}{2a}-\frac{1}{2}}dt,$$
a solution to the differential equation 
$$y''(x)-axy'(x)-by(x)=0,$$
where $a,b\neq 0$ are constants? And if so, for which $x$ it is a solution?

I obtained the solution candidate $v$ by Mathematica and cannot see that it is a solution by direct calculation.

Comment: Try to substitute in the ode and simplify and see if it sstisfies the ode.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I substituted it in the equation and ended up with $\int_0^1e^{(ax^2t)/2}t^{b/(2a)-1}(1-t)^{-b/(2a)-1/2}(a^2x^2t^2+(a-a^2x^2)t-b)dt$ but I don't know how to continue with this.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that, using Mathematica, you obtained $$v(x)=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{b}{2 a}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{b}{2 a}\right)
   \, _1F_1\left(\frac{b}{2 a};\frac{1}{2};\frac{a x^2}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$ provided $\Re\left(\frac{a+b}{a}\right)<2$ and $0<\Re\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)<1$ .

If you take the first and second derivatives, you will see that $$v''(x)-axv'(x)-bv(x)=0$$

If you solve the differential equation, the general solution is $$v(x)=c_1 H_{-\frac{b}{a}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a} x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+c_2 \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{b}{2 a};\frac{1}{2};\frac{a x^2}{2}\right)$$ in which appears the Hermite polynomial.

But I must confess that I do not have any idea of what to do next.

Anyway, may be (I hope and wish) this could give you some ideas for continuing your work.