# A second order ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have a trouble when solving this equation

$u_t = -u_{xx} + ixu_x$

where the initial condition $u(0) = u_0$. In fact, using separable method, let $u(x,t) = T(t)X(x)$. Therefore, we can change the equation to

$T'(t)X(x) = -X"(x)T(t) +ixT(t)X(x)$

Hence, $\frac{T'}{T} = -\frac{X'}{X} + ix\frac{X'}{X} = \lambda$. The first equation $\frac{T'}{T} = \lambda$, we can easily solve. However, the second equation $-\frac{X'}{X} + ix\frac{X'}{X} = \lambda$, I do not know how to solve that. Anyone can help me to solve that ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution for that: $X''-ixX'+\lambda X=0$, try to find solution as series representation: $X(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k$, same question here [Solution to $y''-axy'-by=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668174/solution-to-y-axy-by-0)